# Is the arrow space of a fundamental groupoid of a Hausdorff and second countable manifold always Hausdorff and second countable?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, groupoids, lie-groupoids

Usually in the definition of a Lie groupoid, we do not assume the arrow space to be second countable and Hausdorff.

Now, in particular for  a smooth manifold $M$ with the assumption that it is second countable and Hausdorff, is the arrow space of $\Pi(M)$ always Hausdorff and second countable? Any reference in this direction is appreciated.

Comment: The arrow space of $\Pi(M)$ is a covering of $M\times M$, so the answer is yes.